# Flex - How to get the parameters passed to a RemoteObject call when a FaultEvent is triggered?

Tags: apache-flex, parameters, remoteobject

I call a RemoteObject method inside a loop. This method receive a row id as parameter that deletes the row in a database. Inside a loop, lots of calls could be made at once. Some of the calls could fire a FaultEvent. How do I detect the row id that fired the FaultEvent?

The remoteobject:

`<mx:RemoteObject id="myTableFactory" destination="myTableFactoryFactory"/>`

The loop:

```
myTableFactory.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultFunction);
for each (var myTableRow:myTable in rowsToBeExcludedArray)
{
  myTableFactory.removeMyTableRow(myTableRow.id);
}

private function faultFunction(e:FaultEvent):void
{
  // The main question. How to get myTableRow.id that fired the FaultEvent
}
```

Thanks.

Carlos Lima.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely read up on [AsyncToken](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AsyncToken.html).

Every remote procedure call on a RemoteObject will return one:

```
var token:AsyncToken = myTableFactory.removeMyTableRow(myTableRow.id);
```

There are now two things you can do with this token.

**Add a Responder**

You can add a [Responder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/Responder.html) to each call, which gives you the possibility to have a unique handler for each call:

```
token.addResponder(new Responder(handleResult, handleFault));
```

Be sure to remove your global result and fault handlers before trying this. Also I've used the default `Responder` class here, but any class implementing [IResponder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/IResponder.html) will do.

**Piggyback your id**

You can add new properties to the token since it's a dynamic class. For instance the `id` may come in handy here:

```
token.removedId = myTableRow.id;
```

Or maybe even the entire class:

```
token.removedRow = myTableRow;
```

Now you can find these values in the event handlers:

```
private function handleResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
    trace(event.token.removedId);
}
```

The same principle applies to `FaultEvent`

Comment: +1 from me for the suggestion to PiggyBack the ID.  That sounds like what is needed; and it's a creative use of the ASyncToken I never thought of before.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the idea of piggy backing your AsyncToken (and I don't particularly as is sometime impractical) you can retrieve the details of the original request quite easily.

I use this technique when encountering DuplicateSessionDetected errors with BlazeDS, to null the client id and re-issue the originating request.

```
private function handleFault(event:FaultEvent):void
{
    const remoteObject:RemoteObject = (event.target as RemoteObject);
    const message:RemotingMessage = (event.token.message as RemotingMessage);

    message.clientId = null;
    remoteObject.getOperation(message.operation)
        .send.apply(null, message.body);
}
```

Hope that helps!